# What value does a Method Invocation Expression for a function with void as a return type evaluate to?

Tags: java

The [oracle java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) states: (emphasis by me)

> An expression is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, **that evaluates to a single value**.

Given a function

```
public void doNothing() { }
```

what values does the Method Invocation Expression `doNothing()` evaluate to?

I'm wondering this because in my understanding `void` suggests that this function doesn't return anything.

Comment: `doNothing()` is not a valid expression, because you cannot use it e.g. in `Object x = doNothing()`, or any other expression context. But you can use it as a statement

Comment: The language specification begs to differ. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`doNothing()` is a method invocation, not an expression. As you quoted, an *expression* is a construct made up of *variables*, *operators*, **AND** *method invocations*... that evaluates to a single value. It would be the same as asking if a word, or a phrase is a sentence.

Consider the `Map#put(K,V)` method. The invocation of this method by itself, even when it returns a value, does not represent an expression in itself.

```
1  Map<String, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<>();
2  Integer oldVal = numbers.put("one", 1); // not an expression
3  boolean notNull = oldVal != null); // an expression
```

The main reason why the code on line 2 is not an expression is because no evaluation is being done. Line 2 is a simple method invocation, even though it returns a value. In contrast, line 3 is an expression because an evaluation is being done (the comparison of the `notNull` variable against `null`.

```
1  int value1 = 1 + 2; // an expression
2  int value2 = 5 * 2; // an expression
3  if (value1 == value2) {...} // an expression
```

In the above snippet, all 3 lines contain an expression. The obvious is line 3 (`value1 == value2`). The other two are mathematical expressions. Why? Because each one is a construct that has two operands, and an operator.

Going back to the method `doNothing()`, the invocation of this method **cannot** be used to construct an expression because it doesn't return a value. Therefore, it cannot be used to build an evaluation.

I hope this helps clarify what an *expression* is.

Comment: That's not what the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html) says. An invocation of a method returning void is an expression, albeit one which has restrictions on use.

Comment: @accessviolation from the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3) - "_If the compile-time declaration is void, then the method invocation must be a top level expression (that is, the Expression in an expression statement or in the ForInit or ForUpdate part of a for statement), or a compile-time error occurs. Such a method invocation produces no value and so must be used only in a situation where a value is not needed._" To me this means that a method that returns _void_ as `doNothing()` in the example above, is not an expression in itself.

Comment: It's still an expression.  "Must be a top-level expression" tells you that!  It is an expression that must be one of the particular subtypes of expression.

Comment: @accessviolation The people who wrote the JLS (a more technical document) also wrote the Oracle Tutorials contents which is summarized and less technical. In there, it is clear that an _expression_ must meet a certain criteria. Otherwise, every line of code is an expression which makes no sense.

Comment: "Every line of code"?  No.  `if (a>b)` (for example) is not an expression; it is an if-statement that contains an expression - which is required to be an expression yielding a boolean/Boolean result.

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html) is the authoratative source, rather than a tutorial.

> When an expression in a program is evaluated (executed), the result
> denotes one of three things:
>
> A variable (§4.12) (in C, this would be called an lvalue)
>
> A value (§4.2, §4.3)
>
> Nothing (the expression is said to be void)

Thus your `doNothing()` call is an expression, and your intuition is correct - it returns nothing.

Void expressions are subject to limitations:

> An expression denotes nothing if and only if it is a method invocation
> (§15.12) that invokes a method that does not return a value, that is,
> a method declared void (§8.4). Such an expression can be used only as
> an expression statement (§14.8) or as the single expression of a
> lambda body (§15.27.2), because every other context in which an
> expression can appear requires the expression to denote something.

Comment: Maybe we're splitting hairs. To me, a method that returns `void` is an expression to the VM because it is evaluated. The quote I provided you from the JLS states that the method invocation is evaluated by it (by the VM) and if it doesn't conform to a specific criteria, it will throw an exception. This is not the case for the high-level application which cannot do this sort of evaluation. The authors of Oracle tutorials, which were the architects of Java, appear to make this distinction. Of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: For example, if you declare a method to return `void` and the method body contains a `return` statement that returns a value is evaluated by the VM and as a result, it will throw an compile-time exception. Likewise, if the method is declared to return a value and the method body returns nothing, it will also throw an exception. The **VM** makes an evaluation of the method as a whole to make this determination.

Comment: Maybe it's splitting hairs, but I find it useful to adopt the same terminology as is used in the definition of the programming language.